# Classroom/api: Grade and return api created assignment to only selected list of students

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

just want to ask you if you know the possibility to grade only a list of students for an assignment where there's lots more.

Imagine i have 100 students in a api created assignment and i want to grade and return only 25 using a list in a sheet where i have the email of these 25 students with the grade and comment to patch in a google sheet, but not to change anything to the rest stududents.

Thank you!

Nothing tried yet but want to write a script to batch enter grades to selected students but not hving separate assignments

Comment: This is definitely possible using the Classroom API https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-coursework. Your question is likely too open ended to get a good answer on StackOverflow; see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. That said, this tutorial seems like what you want https://yagisanatode.com/google-apps-script-upload-grades-into-a-google-classroom-coursework-assignment/